# Use Sql LIKE in TableAdapter for int values

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-like, tableadapter

I want to create my own query with parameters in `TableAdapter` configuration wizard.

So after this I use this code but it is wrong :

```
SELECT Name, ProjID
FROM ProjectTable
WHERE (ProjID LIKE @ProjID% )
```

because >> syntax error new ')', it is clear .

After some searching, someone with the same problem suggests to use something like this :

```
SELECT Name, ProjID
FROM ProjectTable
WHERE (ProjID LIKE @ProjID + '%')
```

but it is still wrong and give me this error at runtime :

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.

And it is clear too , because I use +'%' in a query that point to a int data type .

So, how can I solve this problem (I mean create a parameter for a query in `TableAdapter` specially for `int` data types) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot do a LIKE on an int. It is for varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like @ProjID is a numeric data type.  You'll need to cast it to a varchar before appending the % to it.

I'm not sure what sql you're using, if it's Sql Server variation then try

```
SELECT        Name, ProjID
FROM            ProjectTable
WHERE        (cast(ProjID as varchar(30) LIKE cast(@ProjID as varchar(30)) +'%' )
```

You may need to adjust the varchar(30) to something larger or smaller to accommodate the size of your value.   ProjID will be automatically cast to varchar for the comparison but it's better to specifically cast it as well.

This isn't going to be the most efficient query. Because of the cast (implicit or explicit) on the column name it will not use any indexes you have defined for it.

Comment: Great point about this not being efficient.  Casting to a varchar and performing a LIKE operation completely removes any performance gained by having an int column.  I feel like there's a better way to accomplish what the OP wants.

Comment: @Kalmino You may appreciate my answer, for what it's worth. Thanks for pointing out my original mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can only perform LIKE operations on strings.   So you can do this:

```
SELECT        Name, ProjID
FROM            ProjectTable
WHERE        CAST(ProjID AS varchar(31)) LIKE CAST(@ProjID AS varchar(31))+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just avoid the `VARCHAR` mess altogether.

```
SELECT Name, ProjID
FROM ProjectTable
WHERE ProjID = @ProjID OR ProjID >= 10 * @ProjID
```